# Getting 'HPE Unified functional testing computer is locked or Logged Off 'message

Tags: hp-uft, alm, uft14

I am facing below issues while executing the scripts from ALM. There are 5 scripts for execution & execution got stopped after 1st script, due to which status of rest scripts is ‘Not Completed’.
 Reason for not completed script is “General Error. The HPE Unified functional testing computer is locked or Logged Off” . 
While putting the script for night execution, we always run  the screen unlock vbs script which do not lock the machine[ Local & RDP] & this unlock script is working as expected but still we are getting this error.

NOTE: 
1] We work on Remote Desktop Machine where UFT & ALM is installed. Local machine is only to launch the RDP.
2] ALM remain logged in for entire night due to ALM execution scheduler.

Refer attached error screen shot for more details[image]

Answer (score 1):

Within regedit go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional\MicTest

With MicTest highlighted you will see many registry settings. Scroll down the list until you get to SkipEnvironmentChecks.

Change the value of this registry setting to 1 (from 0).

This will cause QTP to not check for the system being locked and will instead kick off your test. However, if the machine is logged off, it will not help. So make sure that the machine you want to run the script on is locked and not logged off and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Sekar Ramu, 
It worked for me. I was able to do the execution of 8hrs